# Joining a table with an unconventional column name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have the following model :

```
class SocUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :id, :name, :username
  has_many :friends, :class_name => 'SocFriend', :foreign_key => 'user_id', :dependent =>  :destroy
  has_many :ownlist, :class_name => 'SocOwnlist', :foreign_key => 'user_id', :dependent =>  :destroy
end

class SocFriend < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :user_id, :friend_id
  belongs_to :user, :class_name => 'SocUser'
  belongs_to :friend, :class_name => 'SocUser'
end

class SocOwnlist < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :user_id, :book_id
  belongs_to :user, :class_name => 'SocUser'
  belongs_to :book, :class_name => 'SocBook'
end
```

A user can have many friends. And each friend is also a user. Any user can have many books. How do I add an association so that a user can access all the books of his friends.

If I add an association in SocUser like `has_many :avail_list, :class_name => 'SocOwnlist', :through => :friends, :source => :friend`

The sql query it generates when we call `myuser.avail_list` is:

```
SELECT "soc_ownlists".* FROM "soc_ownlists" INNER JOIN "soc_friends" ON "soc_ownlists"."id" = "soc_friends"."friend_id" WHERE "soc_friends"."user_id" = 1
```

But the ON condition should be "soc_ownlists".**"user_id"** = "soc_friends"."friend_id", is there a way to specify it?

Or is there any other way to specify the association?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the primary_key for the association

```
has_many :avail_list, :class_name => 'SocOwnlist', :through => :friends, :source => :friend, :primary_key => 'user_id'
```

Comment: Thanks christian. I have already tried it but it did not work.

Comment: Can you try it without `:source => :friend`?

Comment: Thanks Christian. Without :source => :friend i get the following error                        ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the source association(s) :avail_list or :avail_
list in model SocFriend. Try 'has_many :avail_list, :through => :friends, :source => <name>'. Is it one of :user or :friend
?